# TestCafe does not load the base URL

Tags: testcafe

TestCafe does not load the base URL (login page). A blank page is loaded when the base URL is accessed.

```
fixture('Getting Started')
    .page('https://base_url/RRApp/auth/login');

test('My first test', async t => {
    await t
        .debug()
        .typeText('#developer-name', 'John Smith')
        .click('#submit-button');
});
```

The following error was noted in the console.

```
﻿
:51582/HeWNWihUP*hTz…d054cfa21e2582.js:1 Failed to load module script: Expected a JavaScript module script but the server responded with a MIME type of "text/html". Strict MIME type checking is enforced for module scripts per HTML spec.
:51582/HeWNWihUP*hTz…ac00f42bc3886e.js:1 Failed to load module script: Expected a JavaScript module script but the server responded with a MIME type of "text/html". Strict MIME type checking is enforced for module scripts per HTML spec.
:51582/HeWNWihUP*hTz…08841904c1a9ce.js:1 Failed to load module script: Expected a JavaScript module script but the server responded with a MIME type of "text/html". Strict MIME type checking is enforced for module scripts per HTML spec.
scripts.84ac6b0981f52dfb.js:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'
```

**Note**

1. It was possible to access the login page with a normal browser instance
2. This issue was reproducible with TestCafe Studio recording too
3. There was no issue in both scenario when different URL was used. e.g. 'https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/example'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> fixture('Getting Started')
> .page('https://base_url/RRApp/auth/login');

You do not need to add `base_url` here. It works automatically.
Take a look at the following test code:

```
fixture `f`
    .page `./RRApp/auth/login`

test(`test`, async t => {
    await t.debug();
});
```

Then, you can run TestCafe using the following command:

```
npx testcafe chrome test.js --base-url http://example.com
```

See the following articles for more information:
https://testcafe.io/documentation/402639/reference/command-line-interface#--base-url
https://testcafe.io/documentation/402638/reference/configuration-file#baseurl